# I2C - MCP4725 DAC (12bit)

Tags: arduino, i2c

i have **alternative signal** , **want to reconstruction ADC signal with DAC** and see result.

**i'm not Write DAC value** to **MCP4725** for reconstruction ADC signal .

how to done it ?

please help me for solve it
thank's

Comment: just search the web for "MCP4725 arduino"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-output-devices/arduino-mcp4725-digital-to-analog-converter-tutorial/

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MCP4725.h>
#define voltsIn A0

Adafruit_MCP4725 dac; // constructor

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dac.begin(0x60); // The I2C Address: Run the I2C Scanner if you're not sure  

}

void loop(void) {

    uint32_t dac_value;
    int adcValueRead = 0;
    float voltageRead = 0;

    float dac_expected_output;


    for (dac_value = 0; dac_value < 4096; dac_value = dac_value + 15)
    {
      dac_expected_output = (5.0/4096.0) * dac_value;
      dac.setVoltage(dac_value, false);
      delay(250);
      adcValueRead = analogRead(voltsIn);
      voltageRead = (adcValueRead * 5.0 )/ 1024.0;

      Serial.print("DAC Value: ");
      Serial.print(dac_value);

      Serial.print("\tExpected Voltage: ");
      Serial.print(dac_expected_output,3);

      Serial.print("\tArduino ADC Value: ");
      Serial.print(adcValueRead);

      Serial.print("\tArduino Voltage: ");      
      Serial.println(voltageRead,3);      
    }    
}
```